Strange SQL Lock
I intend to perform an operation in MS-CRM 2011 that involves executing the following query on the SQL Server CRM database (SQL Server 2012):
if exists (select top(1) AnnotationId 
           from AnnotationBase (nolock) 
           where OwnerId = @OwnerId) 
    update AnnotationBase 
    set OwningBusinessUnit = @BusinessId 
    where OwnerId = @OwnerId

However, the execution of the above query, which is often time-consuming, results in blocking SELECT queries on tables that have no relation to the AnnotationBase table, for example:
select 
    "new_receptionform0".new_receptionformId as "new_receptionformid",
    "new_receptionform0".OwningBusinessUnit as "owningbusinessunit", 
    "new_receptionform0".OwnerId as "ownerid", 
    "new_receptionform0".OwnerIdType as "owneridtype" 
from 
    new_receptionformBase as "new_receptionform0"
where 
    ("new_receptionform0".new_receptionformId = @new_receptionformId0)

At the database level, there is no relation between these two tables.
Strange point: when I manually execute the update query in SQL Server Management Studio, no lock occurs! But when executed by MS-CRM web app, it immediately blocks many SELECT queries that apparently have no connection to it.
Can anyone explain the cause of this issue and provide a solution for it?

What locking (eg repeatable read, read uncommitted, etc) and transaction (eg auto commit) options are being used by your web app connection? Could it be that you are starting a transaction performing an update but not committing the change?

Use this script https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2020/04/20/sql-server-blocking-tree-identifying-blocking-chain-using-sql-scripts/ to find out what resource exactly is being blocked. Please also show the full CREATE TABLE definition (with indexes) for all involved queries, and plase share the execution plans for the involved queries via https://pastetheplan.com. It's not possiblt to diagnose otherwise.

There never was a SQL Server 2012 R2 - which version are you really using? Run SELECT @@VERSION in SSMS to find out ...

@Bohemian, Charlieface, Thank you for your attention and comments. I understand that Microsoft Dynamic CRM updates all records related to a user in all tables when changing user's Business Unit. This operation occurs within a Transaction. Since the AnnotationBase table in our database has become extremely large, performing this operation on it takes a lot of time and the Transaction remains open, so the tables that were updated earlier remain locked until this transaction is completed. This is a significant problem, as we cannot define Users in new job positions in the system.

Fascinating, but that's not going to help us diagnose the issue. We need table and index definitions and the query plans, as asked.
